# Not all users in an active directory group receiving a workflow notification?

Tags: 2010, workflow, active-directory

I have a Nintex workflow with a flexitask that should send a notification to all users in an active directory group. Currently, users within this group who have been with the company for some time receive the notification but new accounts within the group do not and I'm unsure why.

I've been trying to resolve this issue with Nintex support but they have been no help, giving me the same pre-fabricated response three times now. I have checked the account is a security group (which it is) and can re-produce the issue in my development environment.

What else should I be checking or what could this issue be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few months back I too faced same kind of issues, where the newly added users in the Active Directory were not getting the notification emails. It was because the users in the active directory should be added in the Site Collection also, so that the workflow can fetch the email ID of the users and send mail. To bring all the users from Active Directory to your web application, you have to configure the User Profile Synchronization in the Central Administrator.

Please configure the below in the sharepoint server,

1. Configure User profile Synchronization.

> REF:
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049(v=office.14).aspx

1.1 Once after configuring, you need to set up a Timer Job which keeps the SharePoint 2010 Server in sync with the Active Directory
Schedule User profile Synchronization.

> REF:
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890103(v=office.14).aspx

Once after the above configuration, we can create a Windows task Scheduler to run the Synchronization code in a daily basis (same like #2), to do that please follow the below link.

> REF :
>   http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Sync-user-information-in-d1b9aed5